# Restoring docker-compose.yml from runned containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

On the production server, there was a docker-compose.yml, which was accidentally overwritten, the containers are still running from the old docker-compose.yml, is there a way to get the old docker-compose.yml content from the still running containers

I tried restoring the old file in the terminal

Comment: I doubt that you can. The container does not keep the compose config. Only some labels that are needed for the container management (`docker inspect <container> -f '{{json .Config.Labels}}'`). From `.Config` you can reverse-engineer part of your configuration, but it's not ideal.

Comment: Re-run your deployment process, getting the `docker-compose.yml` file from source control.  Compose will understand that the existing containers go with the replaced file.